# GTK4 Image Which Fills Parent

Tags: gtk4

I am trying to create an image which fills its parent widget in both dimensions while keeping the aspect ratio. In gtk4-rs I did

```
let picture_widget = gtk::Picture::builder()
    .hexpand(true)
    .vexpand(true)
    .halign(gtk::Align::Fill)
    .valign(gtk::Align::Fill)
    .keep_aspect_ratio(true)
    .can_shrink(true)
    .build();
```

But this fills only one dimension of the parent. However, I would like to overflow the parent in that dimension, such that both dimensions are filled.

Generally, I think my goal could be achieved by `child.set_size_request(parent_width, parent_height)`. That needs to be done every time the parent size changes.

Idea 1: Listen to `size_allocate` signal of parent. Does not work, because the `size_allocate` signal has been removed: https://docs.gtk.org/gtk4/migrating-3to4.html#adapt-to-gtkwidgets-size-allocation-changes

Idea 2: Subclass `Picture` and set size in `allocate()`. But `Picture` is apparently not subclassable. The compiler tells me that

> type ParentType = gtk::Picture; => the trait `IsSubclassable<FillingPicture>` is not implemented for `Picture`

Idea 3: Subclass `Widget` and use `Picture` inside (from https://github.com/gtk-rs/gtk4-rs/issues/393). I do not know how to then link all the function calls together such that the `Picture` is actually shown. (It also feels wrong to do this. If this was easily possible, `Picture` would probably be subclassable?)

Idea 4: Reimplement the whole `Picture` class from scratch. Seems overkill and too much maintenance overhead just for a simple resize.

Idea 5: Use CSS properties to fill the parent. I tried setting `width` and `height` to 100%, but apparently relative sizes are not allowed. Also the `cover` CSS attribute is not supported.

Idea 6: Drop GTK

Any other ideas or fixes for the ideas above?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?

Comment: No, I've given up so far. When I get back to it, maybe I can post some more complete code. Not sure if that is why there are no answers here so far. Or maybe it is a really an unsolved problem?
In any case, it seemed to me that some properties are only available through CSS, but not through a library API, i.e. a function call.

Answer (score 1):

Just getting with the same problem yesterday. The one that works for me was the 5th idea...

> Idea 5: Use CSS properties to fill the parent. I tried setting width and height to 100%, but apparently relative sizes are not allowed. Also the cover CSS attribute is not supported.

But using `background-image` instead.

```
box.nameofclass {
background-image: url("resource:///{your_path_in_gresources}/pic.jpg");
background-position: center;
}
```

[image: result]

More info:
[Backgrounds](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-backgrounds-3/#backgrounds)

I'm just beginning with gtk4-rs, so it may not be the best way to do it. It would be great to set this via properties tbh.